# mysql update sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'

Tags: mysql

When running the mysql rpm `mysql-community-server-5.7.14-1.sles12.x86_64.rpm` I get this error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'

That far everything works but I noticed immediately after the update there were 712MB! less on the system disk and I suspect the clean up process did not work well because of the error.

**My question:**

1. Has anybody an idea how to fix the problem even it is a rpm file I download directly from MySQL?
2. Where can I remove manually the temporary files created while the update process?

**Info:**

Linux: SLES 12 SP1

MySQL: 5.7.14

**Clarification:**

I do **not** want to know what the problem means in the `sed` program. I do **not** have any access to the `sed` parameters [I did not write it; it is delivered by the MySQL organization] due to the fact it is ran by the `rpm` program controlled by the rpm file.

Comment: Can you show us the `sed` command so we can get some more clues?  You can probably `cat` or `grep` `mysql_update`.

Comment: You have access to the rpm, I don't.

Comment: Nor am I.  Something like this will find all the seds:  `grep -R "sed"`.  Or you could file a bug report at `http://bugs.mysql.com`.  It does not sound like a 'user error', so they should look at it.

Comment: @RickJames I filed it already hours ago. We'll see. Thx.

Comment: Please add the url of the bug to this Q&A.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs on serverfault

Comment: @AlBundy On DBA.se, we only have an option to move to it Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle confirmed it as a [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82389) and it will be fixed in the next relase.